# when the io request was removed from io queue?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Linux RH5.4 OS, ext3 file system
In time T1, when i read/write a file, a i/o request will be send to OS(disk?) working queue, suppose the disk spend 10 ms to serve this request, now the time is T2=T1+10ms,
then the question is: When the request was removed from OS(disk?) working queue? at T1 or T2?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Up until about 2.6.31, it was up to each individual device driver to decide when to remove requests from the kernel request queue.

[In more recent kernels](http://lwn.net/Articles/336829/), requests are always removed from the queue as the driver retrieves them to send to the device.

If the disk has a queue (i.e. ATA NCQ), a request will remain in the disk's queue from the time when the driver places it there until the driver overwrites it with a later request (after the disk has signalled completion of the first request).  Disk queues aren't strictly queues as there is no head or tail, it's just a pool of command slots that can be started independently.

Comment: Thank you. and do you know how the iostat util was computed? I search Google, cannot find it.